# При загрузке страницы на сервер не отображается элемент (png)

Tags: css, сервер

Приветствую! Дело в том, что в live preview, или если просто забросить html в браузер, все отображается нормально, но вот я загрузил страницу на сервер и один элемент почему-то не отображается... Я совсем недавно изучаю фронтэнд и это мои первые шага, так что не судите строго)

не отображаемый элемент находится в этом блоке:

[class^=stil_]{
        display:block; box-sizing:border-box; background:rgba(160,170,180,1.00); padding:9px 12px; max-width:936px; height:47px; cursor:pointer; margin:2px auto 0px auto; position:relative; color:rgba(50,70,90,1.00);
    }

а вот что именно не отображается:

```
    [class^=stil_]::after{
        content:""; width:31px; height:24px; background:url(images/strelka.png) no-repeat; float:right; 
    }
```

Может кто-нибудь подскажет, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: а если просто перейти по ссылке "вашсайт/images/strelka.png картинка открывается?

Comment: О! Спасибо! Оказалось, что этой картинки просто не оказалось на самом сервере)) Хотя забрасывал все скопом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверьте доступность картинки по ссылке. Советую использовать абсолютный ссылки которые начинаются с `/`. В браузере откройте панель инструментов разработчика клавишей `F12`, перейдите на вкладку `console` и посмотрите нет ли там ошибок 404. Если есть красная строка - значит проблема в пути к файлу.
2. Проверьте не превышают ли размеры картинки размеры указанные в стили для `::after`. Попробуйте добавить `background-size: contain`, что означает уместить фон в заданном контейнере ([читать про background](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background))